# Ellipsoid R function - finding if a point fits in - R script

Tags: r

I have a 3D ellipsoid function:

```
ellipsoid <- function(center=c(0, 0, 0), radius=1, shape=diag(3),
  segments=51) {
    angles <- (0:segments)*2*pi/segments
    ecoord2 <- function(p) {
      c(cos(p[1])*sin(p[2]), sin(p[1])*sin(p[2]), cos(p[2])) }
    unit.sphere <- t(apply(expand.grid(angles, angles), 1, ecoord2))
    t(center + radius * t(unit.sphere %*% chol(shape))) 
  }
```

that makes an ellipsoid with a given center and radius. Then I can draw it using:

```
q <- quads3d(ellips[,1], ellips[,2], ellips[,3], front="lines",
  back="lines", alpha=.5, 
                  lit=FALSE, col=surface.col[1])
```

But, how can I determine if a point (x,y,z) falls inside this ellipsoid? Specifically, how do I figure out the semiaxes of the ellipsoid?

for instance,

```
fitsInEllipsoid <- function(ellipsoid, x, y, z) {
#returns true if (x,y,z) fits inside the ellipsoid
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A point `(x,y,z)` is inside if

[image: (x-x0)^2/a^2+ (y-y0)^2/b^2 + (z-z0)^2/c^2 < 1,]

where `a` and `b` are the equatorial radii (along the x and y axes) and `c` is the polar radius (along the z-axis), i.e. the square root of the diagonal of the `shape` parameter.
The center of the ellipsoid is denoted by `(x0, y0, z0)` (variable `center` in your function).

Comment: but the shape paramater is a 3x3 matrix that has 6 values in it. which 3 are the a, b, and c values?

Comment: It's the diagonal of the shape parameter `diag(shape)`, e.g. your default value for shape is `diag(3)`, i.e. a=1, b=1, c=1.

Comment: hm but wouldn't your equation only hold true if I have a unit ellipsoid?

Comment: just to clarify, if I take the diag(shape), I will get a, b, and c. or is it a^2, b^2, and c^2 that I would get.

Comment: `diag(shape)` gives you the squared values, just plot a simple example `ellips <- ellipsoid(shape=diag(c(9,1,4)));
q <- quads3d(ellips[,1], ellips[,2], ellips[,3], front="lines",
             back="lines", alpha=.5,  lit=FALSE, col="red");
axes3d()`

Comment: and do I need to do (x-mean(x))^2 or is literally x^2/a^2?

Comment: and what about that I don't have a unit circle. should I be using my radius?

Comment: (x-x0)^2/a^2 + (y-y0)^2/b^2 + (z-z0)^2/c^2 if the center (x0, y0, z0) of the ellipsoid is not in the origin of the coordinate system.