# How to determine whether a series of points lie in a 3-dimensional ellipsoid using R?

Tags: r

I generate 3 sets of binomial data where the prior is a  multivariate normal distribution with some mean and variance using the following code in R. What I need to determine does the true values of p (p1,p2,p3) fall within the 3-dimensional ellipsoid space created by the estimates of p (rate1,rate2,rate3). I did a similar problem for bivariate and I used point.in.polygon as the function. Is there something similar for trivariate and for 4-variable? I edited my code how I was able to plot an ellipsoid using the 3 sets of generated data.

```
library(MASS)

  set.seed(1234)

  m<-300

  x<-NULL

  k<-20

  Sigma2 <- matrix(c(.58,.49,.37,.49,.58,.38,.37,.38,.34),3,3)

  eta<-mvrnorm(k, mu=c(-0.85,-2.09,-1.90), Sigma2)

  p1<-exp(eta[,1])/(1+exp(eta[,1]))

  p2<-exp(eta[,2])/(1+exp(eta[,2]))

  p3<-exp(eta[,3])/(1+exp(eta[,3]))

  n<-60

  x1<-replicate(m,rbinom(k,n,p1))

  x2<-replicate(m,rbinom(k,n,p2))

  x3<-replicate(m,rbinom(k,n,p3))

  x<-cbind(x1,x2,x3)

  rate<-x/60

  x<-cbind(x1,x2,x3)

 sigma<-var(rate)

 origin<-c(mean(rate[,1]), mean(rate[,2]), mean(rate[,3]))

 #origin<-c(0.349,0.184,0.148)

  coords<-matrix(c(p1,p2,p3),nrow=3)

  A<-sigma

  cFromO<-coords-origin

  Ell<-apply(cFromO,2,function(c){t(c) %*% A %*% c})<=1

  Ell

  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE     TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Have you checked out `mahalanobis()`?  That may be what your after...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you want to check for a flat elipse the formula for an ellipse is easy to write and would likely be faster, as it can be be applied to vectors:

see original answer with nicely formatted math [wikipaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#Generalised_equations)

(x-h)²/(rx)² + (y-k)²/(ry)² =< 1

with (x,y) the coordinate of your point and (h,k) the origin of the ellipse and rx, ry are the semi-principal axes of the ellipse.

The generalized solution for any dimension is given by [wikipaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#Generalised_equations):

> (x-v)^T A (x-v) =< 1

Where x are the vectors defining the points in your coordinate system. v is the the vector defining the origin. A is, still in your coordinate system, the coordinates of the vectors defining the semi-principal axes of your ellipse.

It translates in R fairly easily:

```
    origin <- c(h=1,k=2,l=3)
    coords <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),nrow=3)
    A <- matrix(c(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0),nrow=3)
    cFromO <- coords-origin
```

and your answer is simply given by :

```
    apply(cFromO,2,function(c){t(c) %*% A %*% c})<=1
```

If you want to apply that to multiple points you can wrap this up into a function, nicely commented in roxygen format:

```
    #' @title Is point in an ellispoid?
    #' @description Returns if each point in a matrix of points is in the ellispoid defined by its origin and its matrix of semi-principal axes
    #' @param points A matrix of points with a coordinate per column
    #' @param origin The coordinates of the center of the ellipsoid
    #' @param A The square matrix defining the ellipsoid: one 
    #'       semi-principal axe per line (vectors)
    #' @return A vector of boolean indicating for each given point if it is in the ellispoid

    IsInEllipsoid <- function(points,origin,A){
        cFromO <- points-origin
        isIn <- (diag(cFromO %*% A %*% t(cFromO))<=1)
        return(isIn)
    }
```

Exemple d'utilisation:

```
    # definition of points
    p1 <- c(1,2,3)
    p2 <- c(4,5,6)
    points <- rbind(p1,p2)

    # definition of the ellipsoid
    origin <- c(h=1,k=2,l=3)
    axe1 <- c(0,0,2)
    axe2 <- c(0,1,0)
    axe3 <- c(0.5,0,0)  
    A <- rbind(axe1,axe2,axe3)

    expect_equal(IsInEllipsoid(points,origin,A),c(p1=TRUE,p2=FALSE))
```

**Edit** 
Then to define the confidence ellipsoid of a multivariate normal you want to use the inverse of the variance/covariance matrix as A and use a chi square coefficient to specify the confidence level as explained [here](http://riotorto.users.sourceforge.net/statistics/confidence_ellipsoid.html). Though this is not the title of the question, you can find hereafter a simple example in R:

```
    # just to make sure everybody get the same draws
    set.seed(1234)

    #-----------------
    # definition of a 95% enveloppe for a 3D multivariate normal
    #-----------------
    # the origin defining your multivariate normal
    origin <- c(0.5,0.5,0.5)

    # the variance covariance matrix defining your multivariate normal
    sigma <- matrix(c(.58,.49,.37,.49,.58,.38,.37,.38,.34),3,3)

    # the precision matrix needed in the calculus 
    sigmaInv <-solve(sigma)

    # the function defining the CV% enveloppe
    ArePointsInCVEllipsoid <- function(points,origin,sigmaInv,CV){
        nDegreeFreedom <- length(dim(sigmaInv)[1])
        cFromO <- points-origin
        areIn <- apply(cFromO,2,function(p){t(p) %*% sigmaInv %*% p <= qchisq(CV,nDegreeFreedom)})
        return(areIn)
    }
    #-----------------------
    # example of use
    #-----------------------
    k<-10000 # number of points to be drawn 

    # random draw in a cube
    toTest <- matrix(runif(k*3,min=-3,max=3),nrow=3)

    # plot the points fitting in the 0.75% confidence region
    library(scatterplot3d)
    toPlot <-t(toTest[,which(ArePointsInCVEllipsoid(toTest,origin,sigmaInv,0.95))])
    scatterplot3d(toPlot)
```

Comment: cmbarbu,This answer was really helpful. I edited my code above to show how it worked and the answers were correct. The only other question was I did this for 1 simulated dataset, If I wanted to repeat this for 300 simulations? I am looking to calculate coverage as to out of 300 sims how many times is the true covered by the estimated ellipse?

Comment: How do you initially define the ellipse from your set of results?

Comment: I used your code to define ellipse function(c){t(c) %*% A %*% c})                     In my code A is the var-covariance matrix sigma for the generated data, or is it ginv(sigma)?

Comment: so is A the variance-covariance matrix or the inverse of it? Accordingly my coverage changes from 100% to 0%

Comment: I am unable to understand the code that is used by the link you provided above. In order to see if the point is in a 95% ellipsoid and not just any ellipsoid(as the above code shows), how should I be coding in r?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the exactly same problem was solved here:

[Ellipsoid R function - finding if a point fits in - R script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224280/ellipsoid-r-function-finding-if-a-point-fits-in-r-script)

For higher dimensionality, I believe that an easy solution given M the matrix of the ellipse and a point p is checking whether the norm of ginv(M)%*%p  is smaller than one.

Comment: The op asked for possibly other dimensions. Hence my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I understood that the aim was to check whether a point on the image space was in the sphere. 
With your approach instead, you are able to know if a point of the domain will later be in the sphere.